# Error editing the Salesforce Wave Dashboard

Tags: error, dashboard, einstein-analytics

I created a dashboard and when I trying to edit it I receive the following error. Not sure what is the actual reason.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: This is simply an error or typo in your json, post your json and we can take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming from one SAQL Query. Kindly check that particular widget where you are using this SAQL Query.
Create a lens from this Dashboard Dataset. Go to SAQL Query Section. Then write this logic there also you'll get this error. Fix it there and the you'll get correct SAQL Query.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE!  This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//salesforce.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).